# Current Company ID variable in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

Is it possible to determine the current company ID value for use in custom programming within Acumatica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The static **CurrentCompany** property of **PXInstanceHelper** will return the current company ID:

```
int companyId = PX.Data.Update.PXInstanceHelper.CurrentCompany;
```

Comment: Just for reference, if you need the name of the company too I use PXAccess.GetCompanyName()

Comment: Thanks guys!  I really appreciate it.